# Can the natural embedding $K\to K[X]/(f)$ be extended to form an isomorphism $L/K\to K[X]/(f)$?

Tags: field-theory

I'm studying for an abstract algebra exam (covering commutative rings and Galois theory). As an exercise, I'm trying to work out on my own a proof of the theorem that, given a field $K$ and a polynomial $f\in K[X]$, there exists a finite extension $L/K$ such that $L$ contains a root of $f$. Of course it suffices to prove this for $f$ irreducible.

The textbook's author simply says something like:

> Because $f$ is irreducible, $K[X]/(f)$ is a field, $(f)$ being a maximal ideal. Now, $X\pmod f$ is an obvious zero.

Nothing further.

This is a bit too terse for my taste, so I've decided to devise a nicer proof (using the same basic idea, however).

But now I'm stuck on the following question:

Let $K$ be a field and $f\in K[X]$ irreducible. Then $K[X]/(f)$ is a field. Also, there exists a natural injective homomorphism (i.e., an embedding) $\phi:K\to K[X]/(f)$ given by $a\mapsto a\pmod f$. So, $K[X]/(f)$ is isomorphic to a field extension $L$ of $K$. But does this necessarily entail that there exists an isomorphism $\psi:K[X]/(f)\to L$ such that $\psi^{-1}$ restricted to $K$ equals $\phi$?

I would like to know because if the answer is affirmative, then the following calculation (with $\alpha=X+(f)$ and $f(X)=a_nX^n+\cdots+a_0$) becomes completely straightforward:

$$f(\psi(\alpha)) = \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{j}\big(\psi(X+(f))\big)^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{j}\psi\big((X+(f))^{j}\big)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{j}\psi\big(X^{j}+(f)\big)
 = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\psi(\psi^{-1}(a_{j}))\psi\big(X^{j}+(f)\big)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\psi\big(\psi^{-1}(a_{j})[X^{j}+(f)]\big)
 = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\psi\big([a_{j}+(f)][X^{j}+(f)]\big)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\psi\big(a_{j}X^{j}+(f)\big)
 = \psi\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{j}X_{j}+(f)\right)=\psi(f+(f))=\psi(0+(f)))=0.
$$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your definition of "a finite extension $L/K$" ?

Comment: @mercio - I don't think this is an issue, but rather how $L$ is defined

Comment: Mercio: A finite extension $L/K$ of a field $K$ is a field $L$ such that $K\subset L$ and $[L:K]<\infty$, where $[L:K]$ denotes the dimension of $L$ viewed as $K$-vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ is viewed as an extension $L/K$ but the fact is that $L$ just
contains an isomorphic copy $K'$ (as field) of $K$ which we identify
with $K$ then we think of $K'$ as $K$ (since they are isomorphic
as fields) and say $L/K$ and not $L/K'$.

So when you write about
the restriction to $K$ it is important to note what this theorem
gives you - $L:=K[x]/\langle f\rangle$ and $K$ is not a subset of
$L$ - but the constant polynomials in the quotient are isomorphic
copy of $K$

Regarding the root $\alpha$ of $f$ in $L$ : let $$\alpha=\bar{x}\in L= K[x]/\langle f\rangle$$
then $$f(\alpha)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}\bar{x}^{i}=\bar{f}\equiv_{\langle f\rangle}0$$

Comment: That's why I said that $K[X]/(f)$ is _isomorphic_ (and not equal) to an extension $L$ of $K$. Or do you mean to say that this is wrong as well? Anyway, thanks for your comment!

Comment: Adding to this, it is quite easy to switch between "contains an isomorphic copy of $K$" and "contains $K$", so you can also think of an extension $L/K$ as an injective morphism $K\to L$. In the case of extensions there's no real difference between the "internal" and the "external" definition.

Comment: @KimFierens - You are proving a theorem that shows there exist an extension $L$
of $K$ with a root of $f$. What I am saying that this theorem shows
only that there exist a field $K'\cong K$ (denote the isomorphism
as $\psi$) and an extension $L/K'$ with a root for $f'=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}'x$
where $a_{i}'=\psi(a_{i})$ . The problem is that a construction of
an extension of $K$ itself was not made, but still, since $K'\cong K$
the theorem say that there is an extension of $K$ (of course the
names of the element doesn't really matter).

Comment: Thanks, Belgi. The main point of my question is trying to justify (in a rigorous manner) the calculation which you have been kind enough to provide in the edit of your answer. What has me confused is why it is admissible to directly multiply the $a_i$ (which are elements of $K$) with the $\overline{x}^i$ (which are elements of $K[X]/(f)$). I'm trying to avoid having to 'hand-wave' my way through this calculation, by introducing an explicit isomorphism $\psi$. But I can't work out whether there always exists $\psi$ such that $\psi^{-1}(a)=a\pmod f$ for all $a\in K$.

Comment: @KimFierens - Being rigor - your are multiplying the $a_{i}'$ and not the $a_{i}$.
The confusion is that that first we treat the $a_{i}\in K[x]$ as
(constant) polynomials and then treat them as elements in the quotient,
so they still 'look' like the $a_{i}$  this calculatio

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! So, basically, we're treating $f$ as a polynomial in $(K[X]/(f))[X]$, after which we evaluate it at $\overline{x}\in K[X]/(f)$, right? But this still leaves the question: why (and how) does the evaluation map at $\overline{x}$ of the polynomial in $(K[X]/(f))[X]$ correspond to the evaluation map at $\psi(\alpha)$ of $f\in K[X]$?

Comment: @KimFierens - Look at this this way: We started with $K$ and $f=\sum a_{i}x^{i}\in K[x]$.
We then defined $L=K[x]/\langle f\rangle$. There is a map $\phi:K\to K[x]$
defined by $k\mapsto k$. $\phi(K)\cong K$. Now define the natural
projection $\psi:K[x]\to L$ by $g\mapsto\bar{g}$. If $a,b\in K$
then $a\equiv b\iff a-b\equiv0\iff a-b\in\langle f\rangle$ but this
means that $a-b=0$ (so a=b) since $deg(f)>0$ . So $\psi(\phi(K))\cong K$
so instead of working with coefficients in $K$ we work with their
isomorphic copy in $\psi(\phi(K))\cong K$.

Comment: @KimFierens - Instead of working with
$f=\sum a_{i}x^{i}\in K[x]$ we work with $f'=\sum a_{i}'x^{i}\in L[x]$.
Bare in mind that $L$ have an isomorphic copy of $K$ which is $K'=\psi(\phi(K))$.
Now, $\bar{x}\in L$ (is not an element of $K'$ ) and is a root of
$f'$. Look again at what we did in short - We looked at $K'$ as
$K$ (formally, using an isomorphism) and at a polynomial with the
'same' coefficients (we just changed their names) and we found an
extension $L$ of this field with a root of $f'$which is what we
wanted except we worked with an isomorphic copy of $K$ instead of
$K$ itself

Comment: Thanks. I understand it completely now.

Comment: @KimFierens - You are welcome. You can c if you see it fit  (http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)